# Function in ChangeNotifier Class Not Called

Tags: flutter, provider, state-management, flutter-change-notifier

I have a Flutter App with Provider as a State Manager. The `ChangeNotifierProvier` is at the very top of my app (ie. above MaterialApp widget).

1. I have a `ChangeNotifier` class as follows:

```dart
class AmountManager extends ChangeNotifier {
  String amount;
  void changeAmount(String newAmount) {
    amount = newAmount;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

2. Then I have another class with a `TextField` :

```dart
class MyTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      //some decorations here
      onChanged(value) {
        Provider.of<AmountManager>(context).changeAmount(value);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

3. And in another class under the Main App, I call the `amount` variable:

```dart
class MyText extends StatelessWidget {
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      Provider.of<AmountManager>(context).amount,
    );
  }
}
```

The problem is the `Provider.of(...)` method cannot be called. I watched some tutorials and couldn't find out the reason behind it. If I use static text instead of the AmountManager object, it works. The program only uses the initial value of `amount` in `MyText` class.

What do you think I'm wrong with?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo, correcting now.

Comment: I can't find `onPressed` field for a TextField, try changing `onPressed` to `onChanged` or if you are using your controller to submit change to `onSubmitted`.

Comment: another typo, thanks.

Comment: Did it solve your problem, or are you using `onChanged` and it still isn't working?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working still :(

Comment: If I run the code with ```onChanged(value) {print('a'); Provider.of<AmountManager>(context).changeAmount(value);     print('b');}``` then it only prints "a" and not "b". The ```changeAmount``` function is not called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `listen: false` when you use `Provider.of()` in `onChanged`.

```
onChanged: (value) {
  Provider.of<AmountManager>(context, listen: false).changeAmount(value);
},
```

See [this](https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/blob/a090037f59aeebfbb991d3310384a6fc88c24e51/lib/src/provider.dart#L197-L204) for details.

Comment: Additional info: According to the author of provider, it seems to be due to a bug in `TextField` that such a misuse does not output any exception. I confirmed that other exceptions occurring inside the `onChanged` handler were not shown either. https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues/380#issuecomment-597686676

Comment: I truly appreciate for the answer. I wasn't expecting ```listen: false ``` is meaningful here. Thank you @kaboc